# VSTS Build vNext Get Sources - Git.exe Warning

Tags: git, continuous-integration, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines

We have **git** installed on our build agent host, but VSTS continues to complain about not being able to find `git.exe` in the `%PATH%`. Has anyone figured out this issue?

#### Build Log

```
2016-06-01T14:15:23.5193018Z Syncing repository: MyRepo (Git)
2016-06-01T14:15:23.9412033Z Running 'git clean -fdx' on D:\BuildAgents_VSTS\A0\_work\22\s.
2016-06-01T14:15:23.9567937Z ##[warning]Git.exe is not installed or the path to Git.exe is not included in %PATH%.
2016-06-01T14:15:23.9567937Z ##[warning]Unable to run "git clean -fdx" and "git reset --hard HEAD" successfully, delete source folder instead.
2016-06-01T14:15:25.7068381Z Starting clone
2016-06-01T14:15:54.6447654Z Checking out dcf2e7a08159a102394f64e79c98e8921ccc4798 to D:\BuildAgents_VSTS\A0\_work\22\s
2016-06-01T14:16:57.8020148Z Checked out branch refs/heads/MyBranch for repository MyRepo at commit dcf2e7a08159a102394f64e79c98e8921ccc4798
```

The biggest problem is that we clone our entire repo each time because of this issue. This is slowing down our CI strategy adoption.

Our Path has `C:\Program Files\Git\cmd` in it which contains `git.exe` but it's not getting recognized by the VSTS build agents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VSTS Build vNext does not use the **System** `%PATH%` but the **User** `%PATH%`. There are (2) approaches to fixing it - either assign the path to the Agent user or edit the registry to extend the user path.

We just added `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd` to `HKEY_USERS\<Build Agent User SID>\Environment\Path`

Comment: Also consider, when possible, just to reboot the server, so the **System** `%PATH%` is automatically applied to all users as intended.